# Make relatively positioned element not affect layout/height

Tags: html, css

I've got an icon, like this:

```
<div class="mydiv">
   <i style="position: relative; top: 3px;"></i>
</div>
```

I want to move the icon down by 3 pixels, which works. But the div still has a greater height to it because the icon is technically expanding the height of the line. How do I make the icon not affect the layout at all, and not make the div bigger in height?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#rel-pos
>
> #### 6.1. Relative positioning
>
> A relatively positioned box keeps its normal flow size, including line breaks and the space originally reserved for it.

Basically a relatively positioned element still affects the surrounding elements. You're looking for `position: absolute`, but heres a trick from the same document

> ...
>   A relatively positioned box establishes a new [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#containing-block) for absolutely positioned descendants. (This is a common use of relatively positioned boxes.) The section on containing blocks explains when a relatively positioned box establishes a new containing block.

So by setting the parent to `position: relative` you turn it into a containing block, which means that absolutely positioned elements contained within will be positioned relative to the edges of the parent rather than the root containing block (the window).

```html
Hello World. 
<span style="position: relative; background-color: red;">
    This will be shown inline
    <span style="position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0px;">
        This will be below
    </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 8):

You should make the parent's position relative and the actual element absolute.

```
<div class="mydiv">
    <i style="position: absolute; top: 3px;"></i>
</div>

.mydiv {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this also works. The other answer is more informative though so I accepted it :)

Answer (score 0):

why not fix it with negative margin?

```
<div class="mydiv">
   <i style="position: relative; top: 3px; margin-bottom:-3px;"></i>
</div>
```